# What is the most efficient method to finding the closest moving "enemy"?

Tags: performance, search, closest

I've seen some questions similar to this, but they were more focused on comparing two different methods, rather than asking in a more general sense.

But what would be the most efficient method of finding the closest "enemy" when both the "enemy" and the current player/NPC is also free to move around?

If the enemies' positions were static, I imagine the most efficient method to determine the closest one is to have a sorted list based on their positions and then using a binary search algorithm to find the closest. However, due to the fact that they are moving around, the only solution I can think of is a simple for loop that iterates through every single enemy and compares the distance to the closest distance, with O(n) for the runtime.

This is not ideal, especially if there are multiple entities on both teams. Say there are 100 entities on team A, and 100 entities on team B. All entities are not user-controlled. This means that every entity on team A will be iterating through all entities on team B, every x seconds, and vice versa. That's 20,000 comparisons every x seconds (if I did that math right).

I don't have any code to share, as this is more of a general question, but I did use the for loop method a few years ago when I made a very simple game, and it worked fine for a small number of entities, but I believe I noticed performance issues at around 30-40 entities.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are trying to solve looks like a **nearest-neighbor search** or a *n-body simulation*.

If you consider a problem where you need to find the *closest element among a list of n elements*, then you need to iterate over all the elements. Thus, the resulting complexity is `O(n)`. You cannot do better because you need to read the whole the input (the n elements).

If you consider a case where you want to *find the closest element of **each** element* in a given list of n elements, then you can do this in a much faster way than testing all possible distances (with a complexity of `O(n^2)`). The common way to solve this consists in putting all elements in a [BSP-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) data structure (such as [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or [Octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree). Such a data structure helps you to locate the nearest element near a location in a `O(log(n))` time. As a result, the overall complexity of this method is `O(nlog(n))`!

Note that updating the location of an element in the BSP tree require up to `O(log(n))` operations. Thus, updating the n elements is computed in `O(nlog(n))` time. This is a bit more costly than simply updating the location of the n element (in `O(n)`), but still relatively cheap!